# Django code only works in debug

Tags: python, django, debugging

Very confused about this one. This code in views.py works, but only when I'm debugging using Pycharm. If I just do `runserver` I get a 500 error.

views.py:

```
def add_post(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = PostForm(request.POST)
    cd = form.cleaned_data
    if form.is_valid():
        print "valid"
        post = Post(nickname=cd['nickname'], body=cd['body'], category=cd['category'])
        post.save()

        return HttpResponse("success")

return HttpResponseServerError("fail")
```

Error as seen in Chrome Inspector

```
     <th>Exception Value:</th>
  <td><pre>&#39;PostForm&#39; object has no attribute &#39;cleaned_data&#39;</pre></td>
```

No attribute cleaned_data? But why...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `cleaned_data` attribute becomes available after calling `is_valid()` on a form. You should move `cd = form.cleaned_data` to below the `if`.

Comment: No idea! It should raise an exception. Maybe something happens within the debug process of Pycharm, like calling is_valid() in a variable monitor / 'watch'?

(btw, if this solved your question, please mark my answer as 'accepted')

Comment: WOW! Had the same problem! It's insane, but the code only worked with debug :/

Answer (score 0):

A Django form's cleaned_data attribute isn't accessible until you call `is_valid()` on the form.

```
form = PostForm(request.POST)

if form.is_valid():
    cd = form.cleaned_data
    ...
```